# Wi-Fi sync missing from iTunes 10.5

Tags: itunes, ios, data-synchronization, wifi

This is really weird. I updated my iPhone to iOS 5 today, along with iTunes to version 10.5. According to [Apple's own documentation](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS4062), I should have an option to "sync with this iPhone over wifi" under the Summary tab when my iPhone is plugged in - but I don't!

Since I can't enable it, my iPhone doesn't "see" my computer when I go to Settings > General > iTunes Wi-Fi Sync on my iPhone, even though both are on the same network.

The only thing I can think of is that it's because I'm running OS X 10.5? But I still have iTunes 10.5 and iOS 5, which is all that Apple says is required (they don't list a minimum required version of OS X itself).

Anyone have any idea how I can enable this?

Comment: I'm gonna take a shot in the dark and say Lion (10.7.2) is required. That particular version has deep hooks into iCloud and I'm sure wifi-sync leaps on those imbedded systems. Again, this is just a shot in the dark.

Comment: iTunes 10.5 runs on Leopard?

Comment: Yep, and PowerPC too!

Comment: Yes, Leopard is minimum requirement. I'm using Snow Leopard and I get the option on the Summary tab.

Comment: I did try resetting/restoring the iPhone completely, and I'm still missing wifi sync. It does seem to be OS X 10.5 that's the cause, though it's not clear to me if it's a bug or a deliberate feature omission.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the minimum requirements are iOS 5 iTunes 10.5 and Snow Leapard 10.6.8. I have Leapard 10.5.8 (and the other requirements) I can't use wifi sync. The option isn't in iTunes. I saw someone say somewhere that they had 10.6.7 and they did have the option until they updated snow leapard to 10.6.8.

Comment: I'm not sure when this was added, but iTunes now says "(Requires OS X 10.6.8)" directly next to my disabled wifi sync option. They must have added that in an iTunes point update.

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed this issue by restarting my macbook's wifi.

Comment: Running OS X 10.5?